# Название ресурса программно

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Хочу менять `PictureBox.Image` на рисунок из `Properties.Resources`, но не хочу делать вот так:

```
Image temp = null;
                imgMain.Image = Properties.Resources._1;
                switch (treeView1.SelectedNode.Index)
                {
                    case 0: temp = Properties.Resources._1; break;
                    case 1: temp = Properties.Resources._2; break;
                    case 2: temp = Properties.Resources._3; break;
                    case 3: temp = Properties.Resources._4; break;
                    case 4: temp = Properties.Resources._5; break;
                    case 5: temp = Properties.Resources._6; break;
                    default:break;
                }
                imgMain.Image = temp;
```

А например так:

```
imgMain.Image = Properties.Resources + treeView1.SelectedNode.Index.toString();
```

Но так не получается, поможете? 
Делал это с `RichTextBox`, все работало. А вот с `PictureBox` проблемы.

Comment: Добавьте тег winforms или wpf в вопрос, что там у вас? ))

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! Исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на примере ресурса-строки:

```
string st = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("стринговоеИмя");
```

подсказал гугл по запросу "Properties.Resources from string"

С картинкой должно сработат что-то вроде:

```
var a = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("стринговоеИмя") as Image;
var b = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("стринговоеИмя") as Bitmap;
```

или

```
var c = (Image) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("стринговоеИмя");
var d = (Bitmap) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("стринговоеИмя");
```

Comment: Я пробовал: "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string" в "System.Drawing.Image"

Comment: потому что тебе нужен другой метод, не `.GetString()` а, скажем, что-то вроде `.GetImage()` - проверь в вижуалке какие там есть методы и выбери подходящий

Comment: Увы прямого .GetImage() нету, но есть .GetObject(). Но с ним непонятно как работать, конвертировать в Image?

Comment: вероятно `.GetObject() as Bitmap` или `.GetObject() as Image`

Comment: ну что, помогло?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает <3